# jgitflow Is it possible to set version to final on release-start

Tags: jgit, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use jgitflow plugin. By default when `release-start` goal is executed feature branch with SNAPSHOT version is created.

Is it possible to configure jgitflow to set release branch version to final on `release-start`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decide to use different flow, since this is not the way how `jgitflow-maven-plugin` is intended to use.